# MySQL RDS DB Instance crashed with error code 6

Tags: mysql, rds

## DB instance is running on mysql version 5.6.35

Please see below for more details...
Is it a bug in this version which needs an upgrade to a later version or there is something to look at the memory parameter tuning.

```
mysql> show variables like 'query_cache_%' ;
+------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                | Value |
+------------------------------+-------+
| query_cache_limit            | 0     |
| query_cache_min_res_unit     | 512   |
| query_cache_size             | 0     |
| query_cache_type             | OFF   |
| query_cache_wlock_invalidate | OFF   |
+------------------------------+-------+
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "sort_buffer_size";
+------------------+--------+
| Variable_name    | Value  |
+------------------+--------+
| sort_buffer_size | 262144 |
+------------------+--------+
Sort_merge_passes=@SMP
Sort_merge_passes rate=@SMP_RATE
+------+-----------+
| @SMP | @SMP_RATE |
+------+-----------+
| 1756 |     21072 |
+------+-----------+
```

DB Instance Crashing consecutively for 2 days at the same time with the same error log as below:

### Logs:

```
2020-04-18 19:24:15 115590 [Warning] Event Scheduler: [rdsadmin@localhost][mysql.ev_rds_gsh_collector] Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Unknown'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
19:28:26 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=262144
max_used_connections=416
max_threads=2000
thread_count=190
connection_count=189
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 1065977 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x40000
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x2c)[0x8d1a7c]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x481)[0x66eea1]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf100)[0x2b5e7d2ad100]
/lib64/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x37)[0x2b5e7e3485f7]
/lib64/libc.so.6(abort+0x148)[0x2b5e7e349ce8]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+0x155)[0x2b5e7db56515]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5e6a6)[0x2b5e7db546a6]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5e6d3)[0x2b5e7db546d3]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5e8f3)[0x2b5e7db548f3]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZSt20__throw_out_of_rangePKc+0x67)[0x2b5e7dba6557]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld[0xa95394]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld[0xa96cbd]
/rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld[0xa97ec0]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7dc5)[0x2b5e7d2a5dc5]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x2b5e7e409c9d]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-04-18 19:28:49 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 117.0G
2020-04-18 19:28:56 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 16180005449622
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2020-04-18 19:28:57 58516 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180010692096
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180015934976
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180021177856
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180026420736
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180031663616
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180036906496
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180042149376
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180047392256
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180052635136
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180057878016
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180063120896
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180068363776
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180073606656
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180078849536
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 16180080849294
InnoDB: 3 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 27 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is 262472787712
2020-04-18 19:29:01 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Starting an apply batch of log records to the database...
InnoDB: Progress in percent: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 
InnoDB: Apply batch completed
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 50483028, file name mysql-bin-changelog.344987
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
2020-04-18 19:29:08 2bc860e82700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 262472780916, 1 rows to undo
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 262472780916 completed
2020-04-18 19:29:08 2bc860e82700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 262472779752, 2 rows to undo
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 262472779752 completed
2020-04-18 19:29:08 2bc860e82700  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id 262472778249, 24 rows to undo
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.35 started; log sequence number 16180080849294
2020-04-18 19:29:08 2bc907606700 InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /rdsdbdata/db/innodb/ib_buffer_pool
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] Recovering after a crash using /rdsdbdata/log/binlog/mysql-bin-changelog
2020-04-18 19:29:08 58516 [Note] InnoDB: Rollback of trx with id 262472778249 completed
2020-04-18 19:29:08 2bc860e82700  InnoDB: Rollback of non-prepared transactions completed
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 2 events
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] /rdsdbbin/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.35-log'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-04-18 19:29:09 58516 [Note] Event Scheduler: scheduler thread started with id 1
```

Comment: you should at least update to version  5.6.47  and see if that helps matters.. But s.6 is very old and should be updated to at least 5.7 or 8.0, that means a lot of work. You should also check for hardware problems and check these logs also.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming, it is about to troubleshoot an rdbms operation and config. Therefore this question is off topic here on SO. The dba sister site of SO is for such questions.

Comment: @nbk , it is an AWS RDS instance, and the compute is 40vCPU, 160 RAM and Storage type General Purpose (SSD)...

Comment: but it must be possible to update at least minor updates. This really doesn't look like a problem that could be solved by programming. The mysql version addresses something wrong. that is a internal mysql problem, but your version is old, so try to update and see if the error doesn't occur anymore, I vited that you get transfered to [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mysql), they are much more versatile and hopefully someone recognizes it.

Comment: Additional information request.  What model AWS RDS are you licensed for? t%, m% or something else? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @nbk, thank you for your suggestion, I do not know how to transfer it to the DBA SE, hence created a new thread in there. Below is the link:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/265396/mysql-version-5-6-35-rds-db-instance-crashed-with-error-code-6 .

Comment: @Wilson, I will post the details asked from the MySQL instance here as well as in the new thread.

Instance class : db.m4.10xlarge
vCPU : 40
RAM : 160 GB

Comment: @Wilson, the output for B,C & D are quite big and not getting accommodated here, how shall I provide it to you. Let me put in my google drive and share the link.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BCNUs54AOzAno0BCLjg9kzA0mUNQqsCb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The same issue re-occurred again today around same time.

Comment: Thanks for your data. Analysis in process. We will try to have suggestions posted to your SE 265396 question within 24 hours.  No need to post in 2 places.  Now you know why I suggested posting results to pastebin.com - space is limited here per question.

Comment: Noted ... Thank you...

Comment: @DineshMishra Any news you can share with this community?